# Is it possible to know which elements got evicted from a window?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In a window process function, is it possible to know which elements got evicted?

Use case:

- Window with a lot of events
- Using evictor
- Reduce function that is computationally expensive

Now, what I wanted to do was something like:

1. Window receives event, adds it to the state
2. Evicts some elements
3. "+1" to the aggregated value, according to the new event
4. "-1" to the aggregated value for each event evicted in 2

Since # evicted elements << # elements in the window, it would be much more efficient.

Does this make sense? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, there's a plan to add support to Flink's window API for optimizing cases with highly overlapped windows. Here is the [umbrella ticket in Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11276). Hopefully this will cover your use case.

As for what is possible right now, I do not believe it is possible to share information between an Evictor and a ProcessWindowFunction.